# git branch command not working, but other command do

Tags: git, github, git-bash

I have a strange behavior with my installation of Git. The usual Git commands work normally: `init`, `add`, `commit`, `push`, `pull`, but when I type any command related to `branch`, it reported:

```
C:\Program Files\Deltares\Delft3D 4.03.01\win64\util\bin\more.exe: C:Program: command not found
```

[image: error image]

```
$ git branch
C:\Program Files\Deltares\Delft3D 4.03.01\win64\util\bin\more.exe: C:Program: command not found
```

Some information about my set up:

- Default installation
- According to the error, it has something related to my Delft3D and more.exe, but I tried to look for any corner in my system variables and deleted any item had Delft3D in it. But still, it does not work.

Some useful information:

```
$ set |grep -F GIT
GIT_EXEC_PATH='C:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/libexec/git-core'
PWD=/d/Workspace/GITtest
            if [ -n "${GIT_DIR-}" ]; then
                test -d "${GIT_DIR-}" && __git_repo_path="$GIT_DIR";
                if test -n "$GIT_TESTING_PORCELAIN_COMMAND_LIST"; then
                    __gitcomp "$GIT_TESTING_PORCELAIN_COMMAND_LIST";
    if [ "true" = "$inside_worktree" ] && [ -n "${GIT_PS1_HIDE_IF_PWD_IGNORED-}" ] && [ "$(git config --bool bash.hideIfPwdIgnored)" != "false" ] && git check-ignore -q .; then
                                case "${GIT_PS1_DESCRIBE_STYLE-}" in
            b="GIT_DIR!";
            if [ -n "${GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE-}" ] && [ "$(git config --bool bash.showDirtyState)" != "false" ]; then
            if [ -n "${GIT_PS1_SHOWSTASHSTATE-}" ] && git rev-parse --verify --quiet refs/stash > /dev/null; then
            if [ -n "${GIT_PS1_SHOWUNTRACKEDFILES-}" ] && [ "$(git config --bool bash.showUntrackedFiles)" != "false" ] && git ls-files --others --exclude-standard --directory --no-empty-directory --error-unmatch -- ':/*' > /dev/null 2> /dev/null; then
            if [ -n "${GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM-}" ]; then
    local z="${GIT_PS1_STATESEPARATOR-" "}";
    if [ $pcmode = yes ] && [ -n "${GIT_PS1_SHOWCOLORHINTS-}" ]; then
                GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM="$value";
                if [[ -z "${GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM}" ]]; then
    for option in ${GIT_PS1_SHOWUPSTREAM};
                    upstream=${GIT_SVN_ID:-git-svn};
            if [ "$GIT_COMPLETION_CHECKOUT_NO_GUESS" = "1" ] || [ -n "$(__git_find_on_cmdline "$flags")" ]; then
    if test -n "$GIT_TESTING_ALL_COMMAND_LIST"; then
        __gitcomp "$GIT_TESTING_ALL_COMMAND_LIST $(__git --list-cmds=alias,list-guide) gitk";

$ cat ~/.gitconfig
[user]
        name = QB-LAPTOP
        email = AAAA@gmail.com
[gui]
        recentrepo = D:/New
[filter "lfs"]
        clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
        smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
        process = git-lfs filter-process
        required = true

$ command -V git
git is hashed (/mingw64/bin/git)

$ git --version
git version 2.22.0.windows.1
```